# How to test Auto Renewal In App Purchase Model

Tags: iphone

I have to implement In App Purchase Auto-Renewal Model in my app. I have created a test user and getting the response from App Store for subscription. When I tap "`Confirm`" then sometimes its state becomes `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` and sometimes it becomes `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`. My problem is that I want to prevent user to use the app if he has not subscribed the app. For that I am trying to track the state of "`SKPaymentTransaction`" so that I can allow or disallow the user to use the app. Such that, if the state is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, only then he could be able to use the app, but I don't understand how its state changes.

One more thing, When I tap on the "`Settings`" to manage my Auto-Renewal, it shows me that my app will be expired on the current date i.e., today itself, but when I tapped on the "`Confirm`" button to subscribe my app for one month then expiry date should be after one month. I don't understand how this whole process is working.

I have read whole documentation of Auto Renewal, but didn't get any help from that.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your first problem. In my case, I can never get SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored called at all. I am debugging why.

Meanwhile, I was facing the second problem you described. When I decoded the receipt, it looks like they keep the subscription valid for 5 mins. Sounds like a feature for testing in sandbox. At least that's what I am assuming.